# Android EditText for multiple unit types

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-spinner, android-textinputlayout

I have a form in Android where the user has to enter their height. However, I have a spinner where the user can select the measurement units (feet/inches, and centimeters), and then an `EditText` where they can enter the actual value

If the user selects cm as their units, I want a single `EditText`. If they select feet/inches, I want to display 2 `EditText` fields

The way I'm currently handling this seems inefficient. I have 3 `EditText` fields: 1 for cm, 1 for feet, and 1 for inches

I then attach an `onItemSelected` listener to the spinner. If the user selects the cm option, I `setVisibility(view.VISIBLE)` on the cm `EditText`, and `setVisibility(view.INVISIBLE)` on both the feet and inches `EditText` fields. If they select the feet/inches option, I just do the visibility in reverse and show/hide the corresponding fields.

Is there a more appropriate way to handle multiple unit types that require a different number of `EditText` fields?

Note: my `EditText` are actually wrapped up in `TextInputLayouts` so I can get Material animations on hints, and its on the `TextInputLayouts` that I'm setting visibility.

The code looks something like this:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //Height unit spinner
        String [] values = {"cm","ft"};
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.input_height_spinner);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        ArrayAdapter<String> LTRadapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, values);
        LTRadapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
        spinner.setAdapter(LTRadapter);

        heightCMWrapper = (TextInputLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.input_height_cm_wrapper);
        heightFTWrapper = (TextInputLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.input_height_ft_wrapper);
        heightINWrapper = (TextInputLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.input_height_in_wrapper);

//Some other code for inflating layout etc.
}

@Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                heightCMWrapper.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
                heightCMWrapper.setHint("Height (cm)");
                heightCMWrapper.requestFocus();

                heightFTWrapper.setVisibility(view.INVISIBLE);
                heightFTWrapper.setHint("");
                heightINWrapper.setVisibility(view.INVISIBLE);
                heightINWrapper.setHint("");
                break;
            case 1:
                heightCMWrapper.setVisibility(view.INVISIBLE);
                heightCMWrapper.setHint("");

                heightFTWrapper.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
                heightFTWrapper.setHint("Feet");
                heightFTWrapper.requestFocus();
                heightINWrapper.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
                heightINWrapper.setHint("Inches");
                break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it using just 2 EditTexts instead of 3. Have a primary `EditText` for both feet and cms and a secondary one for inches if they choose feet and inches. Then you just have to set the hint of the primary `EditText` and toggle the secondary `EditText` visibility.

If you want to optimise your current solution with 3 `EditText` theres a few things you can do. You shouldn't have to set the hint every time they toggle the units, you should be able to just set it once in `onCreateView` since each unit has its own `EditText`. This will drop 6 lines from your method. You could take it further and make a method `toggleVisibility(EditText editText, boolean visible, boolean giveFocus)` but thats up to you.

As a side note you might want to use `View.GONE` instead of `View.INVISIBLE`. `View.INVISIBLE` just makes it not visible but it still consumes its space in the layout. So if this is your layout:

(input1) (input 2)

and you set (input1) to invisible, this is what the layout would look like:

(blank) (input2)

instead if you set (input1) to `View.GONE` this is what it would look like

(input 2)

Comment: Thanks for the tip about hint setting. If I set the CM EditText with `View.GONE` when user selects Feet, how do I bring it back again if the user selects CM from the spinner? i.e. what is the opposite of `View.GONE`?

Comment: setting it back to `View.VISIBLE` will do the job. Don't think of them opposites, think of them more as states. `VISIBLE` is a state where its fully visible, `INVISIBLE` is a state where its not visible but still takes up space, and `GONE` is a state where its not visible and doesn't take any space. None of these states are final and you can safely interchange between them.